# after adding setting observable to empty string do not clear textbox?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have bound an observable to a text input field and on clicking a button I am adding its value to a knockout observable array.
After the push, I am resetting the observable but the text field still displays the value. Below is my code.

```
var data = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "abc" },
    { Id: 2, Name: "def" },
    { Id: 3, Name: "ghi" },
    { Id: 4, Name: "jkl" }
];

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    //data
    self.tags = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.tagToAdd = ko.observable();

    //behaviour
    self.addTag = function () {
        self.tags.push({ Name: self.tagToAdd() });
        self.tagToAdd("");
    };

};


$(function () {
    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Here is my html code:

```
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: tagToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<button data-bind="click: addTag">+ Add</button>

    <div data-bind="template: 'tagsTemp'">
    </div>
    @section Scripts
    {
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
    <script id="tagsTemp" type="text/html">    
            {{each tags}}        
                <span>${Name}</span>
            {{/each}}   
    </script>
```

Please help and guide me.

Comment: its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/b6ksg/

Comment: @Akhlesh are you sure it working in the jsfiddle link? I could see {{each tags}} ${Name} {{/each}} below the text box

Comment: @Sherin yes. you can check jsfiddle link. I think you have added jquery.tmpl.js reference after knockout.js.

Comment: @Akhlesh, Sorry, if I've confused you. I'm talking about the jsfiddle link in your first comment (http://jsfiddle.net/b6ksg/). It doesn't seem to work. I didnt make any changes. In the results pane I see a textbox, button and  {{each tags}} ${Name} {{/each}}

Comment: Its working fine at my end. i'm using firefox 29.0.1. it may have some browser problem or jauery.tmpl.js is not loaded properly.

Comment: @Akhlesh. You are right. It works in firefox 29.0.1 but not in chrome  35.0.1916.153 .

Comment: Oh Yes it will not work in chrome as i have given reference for jquery.tmpl.js from github and it has MIME type ('text/plain') that is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled in chrome.you can see error in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it is working with above bindings and knockout foreach list, Code i used is below:

```
   var data = [  
  { Id: 1, Name: "abc" },    
  { Id: 2, Name: "def" },  
  { Id: 3, Name: "ghi" },  
  { Id: 4, Name: "jkl" }
];

var viewModel = function () {  
    var self = this;  
    //data  
    self.tags = ko.observableArray(data);  
    self.tagToAdd = ko.observable();  

    //behaviour
    self.addTag = function () {
        self.tags.push({ Name: self.tagToAdd() });
        self.tagToAdd("");
    };

};


$(function () {  
    var vm = new viewModel();  
    ko.applyBindings(vm);  
});  

    @{  
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";  
}

    <h3>after adding setting observable to empty string do not clear textbox?</h3>

       <input type="text" data-bind="value: tagToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
    <button data-bind="click: addTag">+ Add</button>

       <div data-bind="foreach: tags">
           <label data-bind="text:Name"></label>
       </div>
```

Please let me know in case this is not the case...